# Are parameters of a method call of a proxied (marshallbyref) object serialized?

Tags: .net, serialization, marshalling, remoting

I'm trying to wrap my head around this to make the correct design decisions.

Say I create a new appdomain B, create an instance of an object O inside it and then pass a reference to that object back to appdomain A, so that A can make calls like:

```
O.SomeMethod(parameter)
```

The code in SomeMethod will run in appdomain B, which is what I expect. **I'm wondering what happens to the parameter and return value**. **Are they serialized using binaryformatter and passed by value, or is a reference to that data just passed between appdomains?**

I'm hoping that it's the latter, which means you can have O.SomeMethod() return large amounts of data with no serialization penalty.

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think that BinaryFormatter has no serialization penalty?  Serialization is what it *does*, the binary kind.  And used unless the argument type derives from MRBO.

Comment: I think you misread what I wrote. "No serialization penalty" is assumed in the case where only a reference is passed, and thus binaryformatter (or whatever is used underneath) is NOT used.

Comment: Let's assume the return value is an MBRO object which contains a 10 megabyte byte array in it. Is that object seralized? If not, and the host tries to read the bytes in that array, does it just get it from the actual memory location the owner appdomain has put it in ?

Comment: An array doesn't derive from MBRO so gets serialized in whole whenever you access it.  Regardless of the outer object.  Necessarily so, it would be very expensive to read each element otherwise.

Comment: hmmm ok. so there is no way to avoid serialization in inter-appdomain communication for raw data? Was hoping that by using appdomains instead of processes, i could chain as many components as they want together, and pass a LOT of data without incurring underlying serialization costs. On that topic, does .NET use binaryformatter underneath the scenes? That means remoting between appdomains would be slower than inter-process communication with something like sockets + protobuf.net (which is 10x faster apparently at serialization) !?

Comment: @HarryMexican, if you are worried about performance, try it! Write a simple application for both cases that matches your requirements and see what the difference is.

Comment: You are right svick. I think at this level the only way to know is to try it. I will try all 4 combinations intra-appdomain/intra-process remoting/protobuf+sockets and report results back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguments that are passed to the function need to pass the appdomain boundary before the method is called. The returned value also needs to pass the boundary (in the other direction).

Anytime an object needs to pass the boundary it's:

1. marshaled by reference, if it inherits from `MarshalByRefObject`; or
2. serialized on one side, transfered through the boundary, and then deserialized. This happens if it doesn't inherit from `MBRO`.

To answer your question, yes, arguments are serialized and then deserialized, unless they inherit from `MBRO`.

Comment: So if you keep going down the MBRO chain, you'll eventually get to down a bunch primitives, which presumably are passed by value? Or are those in shared memory?

Comment: No, if you pass a MBRO, its fields are not serialized. If you execute some method on it and it returns something that's not MBRO, that is serialized.